# Ruby on Rails: unloadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load

What does `unloadable` do?

I saw this in the [pages controller of High Voltage by thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/blob/master/app/controllers/high_voltage/pages_controller.rb#L3). [thoughtbot blogs about `unloadable`](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805560/tips-for-writing-your-own-rails-engine), but am still unclear on what it does.

Comment: As the accepted answer is no longer valid, could you could accept the other answer instead? Thanks.

Comment: For those who are looking for blog this is the updated link.
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tips-for-writing-your-own-rails-engine

Answer (score 45):

It means that when you're running on an environment configured with **cache_classes = false** (like the **development** environment) these classes are going to be reloaded by Rails on every request, so you can place them inside your lib folder or inside a plugin and they will always be reloaded without you having to restart the app (as classes inside lib or plugins are not reloaded by rails on every request by default).

This is mostly useful when you're building a plugin and you would like to do **live** changes on it without having to go through the process of always restarting your app on every test.

You can see the **unloadable** method documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/unloadable).

Comment: This answer I did understand.