# read_inheritable_attribute unexpectedly modified in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

This is happening in Rails 3.0.7 and 3.0.9, WEBrick and Apache.

I have a module `Reportable` that has a method that writes an `inheritable_attribute`:

```
module Reportable
  module ClassMethods
    def add_report(report_name)
      instance_eval do
        write_inheritable_hash(:reportable_report_names,
          {report_name => {:dates => true, :details => 'something'})
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

`Reportable` is loaded in `config/initializers` and a class uses it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Reportable
  add_report :report1
  add_report :report2
end
```

In production mode, the first time I load a page after the server starts, the attribute loads correctly:

```
User.read_inheritable_attribute(:reportable_report_names)
# => {:report1 => {:dates => true, :details => 'something'},
      :report2 => {:dates => true, :details => 'something'}}
```

But on the second page load:

```
User.read_inheritable_attribute(:reportable_report_names)
# => {:report1 => {:dates => true},
      :report2 => {:dates => true}}
```

It works as expected in development, and in the console in production mode. The problem only appears in a POST request on the web server in production mode. What gives?

Comment: A possible workaround would be making a class unloadable. Here you can find it explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853471/ruby-on-rails-unloadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of headaches, the cause was that `read_inheritable_attribute` returned a reference rather than value.

The action throwing the error redirected to another action, which was the true cause of the problem. The module had another method:

```
def available_reports
  read_inheritable_attribute(:reportable_report_names)
end
```

And the other action did this:

```
# @model_reports = a hash of 'model_class_name'.to_sym => model.available_reports.dup
@model_reports.each do |model, model_reports|
  model_reports.each do |name, properties|
    properties = properties.keep_if... # remove per the view's requirements
  end
end
```

Because `available_reports` returned a reference, the `dup` did nothing and the `keep_if` deleted my precious values from the class variable.

The fix was:

```
properties = properties.dup.keep_if...
```

Thanks to those who took the time to check this question out even though there wasn't enough information in it to be answered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried, it works in all environments without problem. Any other details?

---

Otherwise:

- why do you use `instance_eval` since you're working on the model itself?
- you should use a splat to pass arguments

This would lead to:

```
module ClassMethods
  def add_reports(*report_names)
    report_names.each do |report_name|
      write_inheritable_hash(:loggable_report_names,
        {report_name => {:dates => true, :details => 'something'})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in model:

```
include Reportable
add_reports :report1, :report2
```

Comment: It's simplified... `Reportable` is included by many classes, each of which has a different set of reports. Each report is generated with a name (which is used to make a report method) and hash of options (which is stored in `:loggable_report_names` with the report method name as a key). There are also several other methods in the module to make retrieving the report names and their options easier.

Comment: Not the answer... but an upvote for helping anyways. Thanks! I was expecting `read_inheritable_attribute` to return a value rather than a reference.

Comment: Maybe you could create the objects in the 'included' block?

Comment: Yeah tried that too (and a gazillion other things... programming by permutation?), but it didn't work. The question didn't have enough info to be answered, I've put the eventual solution in an answer.